# determination of maximum and minimum value of a function

Tags: optimization

[image] 
What is the value of the value indicated in the question. Please explain the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You are given $f(-2)=3$ and $f'(-2)=0$.

Comment: @khamba were you able to get to 8 yourself or was that answer provided?

Comment: I got it and  and also it matches the answer provided

Comment: Oh awesome then.

Comment: I knew the whole method it just wasn't clicking . needed ur hint .